# Facebook native ad won't click: Android

Tags: android, facebook, listview, facebook-audience-network

I am creating a native ad on android using audience network. The problem is that the ads are shown but do not click.Whenever I click on any of the views I registered for clicking the ad, nothing happens. I am loading the ads into a custom listView with a custom adapter:

```
static StaticListView turning_up_lv; //My custom listview

private static void showNativeAd() {
    nativeAd = new NativeAd(context, AD_ID);
    nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            if (ad != nativeAd) {
                return;
            }

            isAdLoaded = true;
            if ((turning_up_lv.getAdapter()) != null && turning_up_lv.getCount() > 3) {
                ((MyAdapter) turning_up_lv.getAdapter()).addNativeAd(ad, false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

        }
    });

    nativeAd.loadAd(NativeAd.MediaCacheFlag.ALL);
}
```

Here is the code for the custom listview:

```
public class StaticListView extends ListView {

public StaticListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public StaticListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public StaticListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

}

And finally here is the part where I load the ad into the adapter. Note that I have removed some irrelevant parts since the adapter is so long

```
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.turning_up_item, parent,
                false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    if (position == AD_INDEX && ad != null) {
        inflateAd((NativeAd) ad, holder, row);
    } else {

       //Load other listview items
      }
}
```

Here is the code for inflating the ad:

```
private void inflateAd(final NativeAd nativeAd, MyViewHolder holder, final View view) {
        // Create native UI using the ad metadata.
// Setting the Text
    holder.time_tv.setText("Sponsored");
    holder.native_ad_social_context.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
    holder.native_ad_call_to_action.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
    holder.native_ad_call_to_action.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.un_tu.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
    holder.comment_or_caption_tv.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());

    // Downloading and setting the ad icon.
    NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
    NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, holder.ad_iv);


    // Downloading and setting the cover image.
    NativeAd.Image adCoverImage = nativeAd.getAdCoverImage();
    int bannerWidth = adCoverImage.getWidth();
    int bannerHeight = adCoverImage.getHeight();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int mediaWidth = holder.native_ad_media.getWidth() > 0 ? holder.native_ad_media.getWidth() : metrics.widthPixels;
    holder.native_ad_media.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            mediaWidth,
            Math.min(
                    (int) (((double) mediaWidth / (double) bannerWidth) * bannerHeight),
                    metrics.heightPixels / 3)));
    holder.native_ad_media.setAutoplay(AdSettings.isVideoAutoplay());

    holder.native_ad_media.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

    addLoadedToMediaView = true;

    final ArrayList<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
    clickableViews.add(holder.native_ad_media);
    clickableViews.add(holder.native_ad_social_context);
    clickableViews.add(holder.native_ad_call_to_action);

    nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(view, clickableViews);
}
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue, did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: I ended up using a recyclerview instead of a staticlistview which ended up doing the trick

Comment: I am already using a recycler view, still the ads are not clickable in some spots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using view holders for the UI elements and prefetching the ads before actually rendering them did the trick